# Listen to either web port, remoting port or both

Tags: java, port, jboss7.x, remoting

I have a quite a few jboss servers, some of which deploy beans, some deploy webservlets and some both. I dont want 3 different standalone.xml. I want that the app that deploys only beans should only listen on one port(remoting port). Similarly the jboss that deploys webservlets should only listen on catalina port. And finally the apps that deploy both ejb and servlets should listen on boht catalina and remoting port. I still want to keep one standlone.xml file